# diffence of saving and loading a file in tensorflow and python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to ask that the syntax for  saving and loading a file in python and tensor flow is different or same?
How can i reload such results
np.save("Result/"+FLAGS.result_file,W)

Answer (score 1):

If you are loading numpy files you can use `np.load()` to get the results back into a numpy array.

```
x = np.load("Result/"+FLAGS.result_file)
```

If you want to save a tensorflow graph, you need to create a saver object after you create your tensors.

```
x = tf.Variable(..., name="x_saved")
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
...
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

Then use the saver object to save the graph to file.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  # Do some work with the model.
  ..
  # Save the variables to disk.
  save_path = saver.save(sess, "Result/"+FLAGS.result_file)
```

When you want to load the model, you need to create same sized tensors, and create a saver object. If you load all your tensors from file, you don't need to call *initializer*.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

and restore the session using that saver.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Restore variables from disk.
  saver.restore(sess, "Result/"+FLAGS.result_file)
```

This will load the tensors with values you've saved earlier. If you want to save and load specific tensors only, you can initialize saver object with the names of those tensors.

```
x_loaded = tf.Variable(..., name="x")
saver = tf.train.Saver({"x_loaded": x})
```

Bear in mind, If you load some tensors and not the whole graph, you need to initialize any other tensors.